# Integrate WPF application and SQL Lite to a single executable which can be easily shared and installed with just one exe file .

Tags: wpf, sqlite

Is it possible to Integrate WPF application and SQL Lite to a single executable which can be easily copied to a system and installed with just one exe file? Any useful links ? Steps to be done for achieving the need ? Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Copy the sqlite file in your project and set the 'BuildAction' to 'Content' from property window.
Check for more information here:- 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970494(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you . Will try the steps .

Answer (score 0):

Reference [the official NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite) (or [the Core package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/) if you don't need Linq/EF support).

Usage is similar to other data connectors in .net. Just use the System.Data.SQLite namespace.

If you want to embed your database file in your assembly, you can do as AjS said, but you will have to write it to a temporary file in order to connect to it.

You should also consider creating your database when your application initializes, if that is relevant to your case. This is trivially done by using the following method:

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("YourFilePath");
```